# update+order by in same query mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, limit

Her are my table structures:

Table1:track_data

```
| device_id(foreign) | latitude | longitude | activity |
```

-Stores id, location co-ordinates, activity being the time instant they were inserted.

---

Table2:user_devices

```
| device_id(primary) | park_lat | park_long |
```

Stores id, park_lat/park_long need to be stored with latitude/longitude from track_data table on request(i.e., the latest activity data).
Now, how will i store the latest latitude/longitude from Table1 to Table2, in a single query. Is this possible, To mix select and update in same query?

And now my non-functioning intuitive query:)

```
UPDATE user_devices,track_data
SET user_devices.park_lat = latitude,user_devices.park_long = longitude  
WHERE user_devices.id='33' AND track_data.activity=(SELECT activity FROM track_data 
ORDER BY track_data.activity DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update user_devices 
join (select device_id, latitude, longitude, activity
      from (select device_id, latitude, longitude, activity
          from track_data order by device_id, activity desc) x
      group by device_id) latest_lat_long on latest_lat_long.device_id = user_devices.device_id
set 
park_lat = latest_lat_long.latitude,
park_long = latest_lat_long.longitude;
```

How this works:

- The inner-most query orders by device_id then activity latest first
- The next layer gets just the first record for each device_id (the latest, because we ordered it thus)
- We then join this to our table so we only need one pass over track_data
- Finally we update the columns

This query will perform very well, because it isn't doing a query per row like some people would instinctively do.

Comment: Thanx for the answer @Bohemian , updates the latest columns. But, I had to modify your query to pass single device_id instead of grouping it. `update user_devices 
join (select device_id, latitude, longitude, activity
      from (select device_id, latitude, longitude, activity
          from track_data WHERE track_data.device_id='33' order by activity desc)x) latest_lat_long on latest_lat_long.device_id = user_devices.id 
set 
park_lat = latest_lat_long.latitude,
park_long = latest_lat_long.longitude;`