# UPDATE tableName, (SELECT @id := 0) dm SET sale_id = (@id := @id 1)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate` (
  `candidate_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roll_no` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `candidate_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`candidate_id`),
  KEY `candidate_name` (`candidate_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

What I need to do is to assign **roll_no** to candidates in a **particular batch**. i.e. there **roll_no will start from 1 for each batch_id**. *(Needless to say there are thousands of candidates per batch or batch_id)*. The value of roll_no field is 0 by default.

What I tried doing:

```
UPDATE candidate c, (SELECT @id := 0) serial
SET roll_no = (@id := @id + 1)

WHERE c.batch_id = 5
ORDER BY c.candidate_name ASC
```

Resulting in: Incorrect use of UPDATE and ORDER BY
If I omit the ORDER BY clause, it works fine, but I need to assign the roll_no to candidates according to the ascending order of their names
Is there any way of achieving what I am trying ... and most importantly, am I clear?
Thanking you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!! This did the trick

```
UPDATE candidate c
JOIN (SELECT candidate_id, candidate_name FROM candidate ORDER BY candidate_name ASC) co ON (c.candidate_id = co.candidate_id)
JOIN (SELECT @a:=0) dm
SET roll_no = (@a:=@a+1)
WHERE batch_id = 5
```

Got some idea from
[update+order by in same query mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003154/updateorder-by-in-same-query-mysql)

Erik Lukman, Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Will this working?

```
SET @id := 0;
UPDATE candidate c
SET roll_no = (@id := @id + 1)
WHERE batch_id = 5
ORDER BY candidate_name ASC;
```